# Compile SASS to CSS using ANT build task

Tags: css, ant, build, sass

I am successfully able to compile my SASS into CSS by using the following script in my build.xml file

```
<apply executable="sass.bat" dest="${css.dir}" verbose="true" force="true" failonerror="true">
    <arg value="--unix-newline" />
    <srcfile />
    <targetfile />
    <fileset dir="${sass.dir}" includes="**/*.scss,**/*.sass" excludes="**/_*" />
    <firstmatchmapper>
      <globmapper from="*.sass" to="*.css" />
      <globmapper from="*.scss" to="*.css" />
    </firstmatchmapper>
  </apply>
  <echo message="Done compiling scss files!" />
</target>
```

How can I pass SASS options as arguments? For instance I would like to compile the SASS to a --style:compressed state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<arg value="--unix-newlines" />
```

will work. So will other command-line arguments to the compiler as long as you include them as separate "arg"s

Answer (score 2):

You are already passing arguments to sass.bat. See the line

```
<arg value="--unix-newlines" />
```

You can add as many `arg` element as you need.

See http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#arg

Comment: Is this an argument for <apply> rather than the SASS compile because if you look at the SASS documentation it says that the option for unix new line is actually "--unix-newlines". If I use this instead of "--unix-newline" the compile fails

Comment: `arg` is the element of `apply` which is passing the value to the arguments of SAAS.